# clientId may Changed 

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery

`<input type="button" id="a" runat="server"/>`

when get viewSource Page `<input type="button" id="ct00_a" runat="server"/>`

i can use clientId for work it

```
$("#ct00_a").text("text");
```

Comment: You cannot use `text()` on `input` elements, because they have no content (maybe you want `val()` to set the value). But what is your question? You have not asked anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET changes ID's to suit its needs of controls.

If you are using ASP.NET 4, you can use `ClientIDMode` set to `static`. That way the ID will be the same as you provide it.

For other versions - use `$('<%= a.ClientID %>').text('text');`

Comment: No - there is no such thing as `runat="client"`.

Comment: `ClientID` is a server side property which is what is generated by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$("input[id$='a']")
```

This jQuery selector can query for elements with an ID that ends with a given string.

Asp.NET is known for adding prefix to id.
For example if you put your control in some container (other server control) it will add it's parent prefix before original id.